# Python scope and loop confusing

Tags: loops, scope

I am new to python.

May I ask why the sixth outcome is 8 instead of 5? As I learnt from "scope" that the later statement should not be affected by whatever happened in another inner scope, so i+=3 should have no effect on what "i" is going to be printed? Thank you for the help.

```
for i in range (0,10):
    if i==5:
        i+=3
    print i




outcome:
0
1
2
3
4
8
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you created a condition that if the i reaches number 5 it will add +3 giving an 8.

the += adds do not replace.

if you expect that change the number 5 with a 3 try:

```py
for i in range (0,10):
    if i==5:
        i = 3
    print i
```